# How to know character encoding of file names depending on the filesystem

Tags: filesystems, filenames

I would like to know the character encoding of the file names in a filesystem in order to display correctly them in a GUI.

How should I do this ?

I suppose I get different character encoding depending on the file system (FAT, NTFS, ext3, etc.)

Thank you

(I work in C++ but this topic is not language related)

Comment: It depends on the filsystem itself. Some filesystems support character encoding, and some only one. And most don't store the encoding in the filesystem itself since the encoding is already defined by its specifications document. You'll have to manually store these information in your own database.

Comment: This really depends on the API, and thus platform (OS) you are using. However, in C++17 might be the filesystem standard library complete and included, which should probably solve this problem somehow.

Answer (score 7):

NTFS is Unicode (UTF-16). exFAT is Unicode as well.

Original FAT and fAT32 use OEM character set (read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

On Linux and Unix filename may contain any bytes except NUL and the charater set is not defined. Consequently each application decides itself which one to use. Many applications use UTF8. See more in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-charset-encoding-is-used-for-filenames-and-paths-on-linux).

The above unix approach is used on most filesystems (mainly because the "charset" concept has more meaning on the OS level than on the storage level). You can check FS capabilities and requirements regarding filename characters [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) (table 2 column 3).

Comment: Unicode is an abstract representation, not a byte representation. You need an encoding to convert unicode to bytes.

Comment: @user803422 "Unicode" as in Windows stands for UTF16. I've updated the answer.

Comment: On my windows 7 - NTFS drive, file names are in UTF-8. So the UTF-16 is not a general rule. The MSDN explanation is rather complicated.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'Callback "Unicode" as in Windows (and Java, and JavaScript) stands for [WTF-16](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/#wtf-16), if anything, and as far as I know NTFS *et al.* will indeed allow unpaired surrogates in names.

Comment: @user803422 That would seem to be impossible, given that the [on-disk format](https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/file_name.html) stores the file name as a counted sequence 16-bit little-endian integers.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux run then following command: locale | egrep "LANG=" | cut -d . -f 2

On Unix-like systems, the encoding of file names is not set at the filesystem level, but rather in the user environment. For instance, UTF-8 is the default setting in Ubuntu.

On Windows default encoding is CP-1252 (AKA ISO-8859-1 or Latin-1), but FS uses Unicode via UTF-16 encoding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename.

But if you use Qt, you can build the following with Qt Creator and result be the current user encoding name.

```
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Q_UNUSED(argc); Q_UNUSED(argv);
  QTextCodec* tc = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();

  cout << "Current names text codec: " << tc->name().data() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ISO 8859-1 and Latin-1 are the same thing, but Windows-1252/CP-1252 is slightly different:
"This encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1, but differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)