# How to create a directory with "/" in its name in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, special-characters

Trying to create a directory with "/" in its name in Linux (Suse). I've heard answers about special characters in general, but here I'm specifically looking for a solution for "/".

Comment: Filenames and character sets depend on the filesystem, which you did not state. Also see [Several questions about file-system character encoding on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15419/56041) and [How to know character encoding of file names depending on the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12237195/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having any specific knowledge, I don't think that's possible. '/' marks a subdirectory in a file path. If the subdirectory name contained '/' then the file path would be ambiguous. 
E.g. 'myNew/Folder' would be equal to the folder 'myNew' containing the subFolder 'Folder' --> '/myNew/Folder'.
And to add - '/' in this case wouldn't be just be a special character (like ä,ö,ü in German) but a command character with a specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
The character `/` is not allowed to appear in file names, including directory names. It is always interpreted as a separator between pathname components.